# How to access HAProxy using java programming

Tags: java, api, haproxy

I am using HAProxy to setup my load balancer. Who can tell me whether HAProxy has java API for accessing? I want to access the configuration information of HAProxy using java programming and configure it. For example, I want to add a new server dynamically through Java API.

Dahai

Answer (score 2):

You could try:
http://dev.vaadin.com/svn/incubator/Arvue/ArvueMaster/src/org/vaadin/arvue/arvuemaster/HAProxyController.java

Vaadin is under an Apache v2 license.

I didn't go very far down the list of google hits before finding that.

You may find that JNA will be the way to go.  JNA is supposed to be pretty easy, compared to JNI at least.